# Разделить одну строку на две

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Дана строка, в которой записаны две последовательности символов через пробел. 
Нужно разделить их на 2 отдельные строки, пробел удалить.

Пример ввода:

```
string1 = sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe
```

Пример вывода

```
string1 = sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm

string2 = bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, через `string` или C-строки.

Итак, если известно, что пробел один...

Решение через строки C++.

```
string str = "sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe";

auto pos = str.find(" ");
if (pos != string::npos)
{
    string s1 = str.substr(0,pos);
    string s2 = str.substr(pos+1);
    cout << s1 << endl << s2 << endl;
}
```

Со строками C:

```
char str[] = "sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe";

char * c = strchr(str,' ');
if (c != 0)
{
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    strcpy(s1,str);
    s1[c-str] = 0;
    strcpy(s2,c+1);
    cout << s1 << endl << s2 << endl;
}
```

Естественно, это лишь одни из множества вариантов..

Comment: @Даниил Потому-что пробел есть, вам нужен `std::getline(std::cin, str);` или типа того. P.S. зря комментарий удалили с примером кода, из словесного описания вообще не понятно почему не работает =)

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему код не работает. Пробовал вводить различные строки, как из цифр, так и из букв. Работает только со строкой, которую вы (и я) указали в примере, а когда ввожу строку через "cin", программа ничего не выводит.
Код такой же как в первом примере ответа, но вместо 
 `string str = "sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe"; `
использовал
`string str;
    cin >> str;`
И ещё, может кто-нибудь знает, как адаптировать его под c++ 14? auto pos не работает.

Comment: Потому что чтение `cin >> str` читает **только одно слово**, до пробела. Чтобы читать всю строку - надо использовать `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

Если пробел один (и для результатов (sttring2 и string3) выделено достаточно памяти), то

```
sscanf(string1, "%s %s", string2, string3);
```

Если же требуется разделить строку `string1` по первому пробелу и учесть вариант, когда нет ни одного пробела, то можно написать что-то в таком духе

```
 ....
 char *p = strchr(string1, ' ');

 if (p) {
   strncpy(string2, string1, p - string1);
   string2[p - string1] = 0;
   strcpy(string3, p + 1);
 } else {
   string3[0] = 0;
   strcpy(string2, string1);
 }
```

Comment: пфффф, ну тогда уж: `std::cin >> s1 >> s2;` - где s1,s2 - `sdt::string`. Там в вопросе метки C не было, только C++. Ну то есть std::sscanf (если подключен cstdio)

Comment: @vegorov, [C++ damages the brain … – EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) (EWD -- это [Edsger Wybe Dijkstra](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5))

Comment: есть такое =) Но всё равно, в вопросе нет метки Си, есть метка C++, Ваше решение предлагает Сишный подход. Он естественно работает, но всё же =)

Answer (score 2):

еще можно вот так:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s="sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe";
    stringstream ss(s);
    string s1,s2;
    getline(ss,s1,' ');
    getline(ss,s2,' ');
    cout<<s1<<"\n"<<s2;
}
```

можно написать это функцией что бы делила кучу слов сразу, передать надо саму строку и символ дележки:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string s,char delim){
    string temp="";
    stringstream ss(s);
    vector<string> vec;
    while(getline(ss,temp,delim)){
        if(temp.length()){
            vec.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

int main(){
    string s="sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe adadad, 123123";
    vector<string> ans;
    ans=split(s, ' ');
    for(const auto& a:ans)
    cout<<a<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string s1 = "sdkmaskmdawekqwemkqwekmqwekm bqmekwmqwekmqewkqwemkkmwqe", s2, s3;
std::stringstream(s1) >> s2 >> s3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне такой вариант, найденный на просторах сети понравился, больше подходит если разделителей несколько

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string sString = "bla.bla.bla";
    std::string sResult = "";
    char cSeparator = '.';

    for (size_t p = 0, q = 0; p != std::string::npos; p = q)
    {
        sResult = sString.substr(p + (p != 0), (q = sString.find(cSeparator, p + 1)) - p - (p != 0));
        std::cout << sResult << "\n";
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
bla
bla
bla
```